# "Who" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, relative-pronouns

In this song of *Hunger Games* [The hanging tree], there's this part that seems odd to me:

> Are you coming to the tree, where they strung up a man they say **who** murdered three.

Why is "Who" used here? Is it a relative pronoun, or something similar?

I believe "who" is used to substitute "a man". However, it sounds very odd to me, since I haven't ever heard something likewise.

However, if "who" is really substituting the noun "man", does that mean I could say:

> They didn't like Maria. They said **who** was not such forthcoming person.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a *song*.  Regular grammar rules do not necessarily apply.  Words in song lyrics (and poetry) are often reordered to better fit the meter or rhyme scheme.  Words may also be shortened, lengthened, elided (multiple words combined into one), repeated, or omitted entirely if it makes it sound better.

Answer (score 4):

*They say* in parenthetical:

> This is a man who murdered three.
>
> This is a man, they say, who murdered three.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I thought there was the implied relative clause "That"

Comment: It's an awkward word order; you probably wouldn't use it in prose, but in verse the words sometimes have to be twisted slightly to fit the rhythm.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *who* is a relative pronoun.
By the way, the word-order here is a little confusing:

> . . . they strung up a man they say who murdered three.

It suggests they may not have strung him up: it's just a rumour.

If it we change it to:

> . . . they strung up a man who they say murdered three.

it means they **did** string him up. He was rumoured to have killed three.

In your second example:

> They didn't like Maria. They said who was not such forthcoming person.

you are trying to use the relative pronoun to link to the previous sentence. Relative pronouns link one **clause** to another. Maria is out of reach! You need to say:

> They didn't like Maria, who they said was not such a forthcoming person.

Comment: I now understand it. I don't hear this type of sentence very much, that's why I found it odd. Thanks for the kind answer.

Comment: Why would you use "whom" here? "Whom" would usually replace "her" ("They didn't like Maria. They hated *her* from the start" => "They didn't like Maria, *whom* they hated from the start") but not "she" ("They didn't like Maria. *She* hated them too." => "They didn't like Maria, *who* hated them too."). Here the sentences being linked are "They didn't like Maria. They said *she* was not such a forthcoming person" - right?

Comment: @psmears Quite right. I'll amend it. I was thinking it was in the form "...Maria, whom they said they would kill". (It was very late!)

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence:

> Are you coming to the tree, where they strung up a man they say who murdered three.

**who** has the same meaning of a **which** or a **that**. However, in general when we are talking about people we use the relative pronoun: **who**.

Comment: I think you mean "the relative pronoun, who".

Comment: Noted and fixed. Thanks!